# firefox extension with native messaging application not working

Tags: firefox-addon, chrome-native-messaging

I have a native application developed in Java (compiled jar) , the extension basically sends message to the native application with the user input and get response back into a label on to the web page.

The extension is working fine with Chrome but I am not able to execute the same in Firefox 58.0.1(quantum 64 bit).

Error in the browser console.

can not convert null to object

below is the snippet code and the error screenshots.

```
   {
    "manifest_version":2,

    "name":"Firefox Automation Extension",
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"Automation Extensions",

    "icons": {
      "16": "icons/synergy.png"
    },

    "browser_action":{

      "default_icon": {
       "32" : "icons/synergy.png"
      },
      "default_title": "Native Messaging Application Testing",
      "default_popup": "index.html"      
},
    "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
          "id": "webdom@oracle.com",
          "strict_min_version": "58.0"
        }
      },
        "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

    "permissions": [
      "nativeMessaging", "<all_urls>"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": [
            "jquery-1.12.2.min.js", 
            "contentScript.js"
          ]
        }
      ]

}
```

/* background.js */

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.info("Received %o from %o, frame", msg, sender.tab, sender.frameId);

```
// As it is registered in registy
var host_name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Open port (for communication).
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative(host_name);

// Send message to native application.
port.postMessage(msg);

// Listen for response...
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    // Send data to the content.
    browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg, function (response) { });
    });
});

port.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
    console.info("Disconnected.");
});
```

});

/* contentScript.js */

```
document.addEventListener("send-message-event", function (data) {

    var request = data.detail.data;
    console.log("content script : ", request);
    // Send message to the background script
    browser.runtime.sendMessage(request, null);
});

/**
 * Listens to the background script and dispatches 'get-message-event' 
 * to the client when the data is received.
 */
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(response);
    // Send response to the front page
    var event = new CustomEvent("get-message-event", {
        detail: {
            data: response
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

/* Main.js (script called from a html page )*/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sendMessageBtn = $('#send-message-button');
    var inputElem = $('#input-text');
    var responseElem = $('#response');

    /**
     * Send message operation
     */
    sendMessageBtn.click(function () {
        var request = {};
        request.message = inputElem.val();

        var event = new CustomEvent("send-message-event", {
            detail: {
                data: request
            },
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        });

        console.log("From Main : ",event.detail.data);
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    });

    /**
     * Get message event listener
     */
    document.addEventListener("get-message-event", function (data) {
        var responseObject = data.detail.data;
        responseElem.text(responseObject.message);
    });
});
```

index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Native Messaging</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Native Messaging</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-text">Input message:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id='input-text' type='text' value="Test" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id='send-message-button'>Send Message</button>
                <hr>
                <div class="well well-lg" id='response'>Response from Native app...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- jQuery and JS files -->
    <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

While clicking on the send Message button I am getting can not convert null to object error.

the code is working fine in Chrome and i am able to get response from the Native application in chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you have not registered your native application in regedit in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts
```

I would put in permission :

```
"tabs",
"nativeMessaging",
"<all_urls>",
"webNavigation"
```

to work with your browser.